# Compilation when trying to convert error from an external crate into my custom error type with `thiserror`

Tags: rust, error-handling, thiserror

I am trying to use the [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) crate to convert an error into my custom error but I am getting this compilation error message. The error I am trying to implement is the [MiddlewareError from the Ethers-rs crate](https://docs.rs/ethers/1.0.2/ethers/contract/enum.ContractError.html#variant.MiddlewareError). Below is the compilation error I am getting.

```
`?` couldn't convert the error to `CFFMError<M>`
the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
required because of the requirements on the impl of 
`FromResidual<Result<Infallible, <M as Middleware>::Error>>` for `Result<(), CFFMError<M>>

consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement: ` where CFFMError<M>: From<<M as Middleware>::Error>`
```

My error type is defined as

```rust
use ethers::prelude::gas_oracle::MiddlewareError;
use ethers::prelude::{AbiError, ContractError};
use ethers::providers::{JsonRpcClient, Middleware, Provider, ProviderError};
use ethers::types::H160;
use thiserror::Error;
use tokio::task::JoinError;
use uniswap_v3_math::error::UniswapV3MathError;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum CFFMError<M>
where
    M: Middleware,
{
    #[error("Middleware error")]
    MiddlewareError(#[from] MiddlewareError<M>),
//--snip--
}
```

When trying to add the following, I get another error saying

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<error::CFFMError<_>>` for type `error::CFFMError<_>`
conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
- impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

```rust
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum CFFMError<M>
where
    M: Middleware,
{
    #[error("Middleware error")]
    MiddlewareError(#[from] MiddlewareError<M>),

    #[error("some error message")]
    OtherMiddlewareError(#[from] M::Error),
//--snip--
}
```

Can anyone help advise on what do to to resolve this compilation error?

Comment: What if you happen to have a `Middleware` with `M::Error = CFFM<M>`? In that case, you'll have two possible `From`s - wrapping it in `OtherMiddlewareError` and passing as-is.

Comment: Hmmm, what do you think the best way to design around this is? I just need to handle all external crate errors and transform them into a CFFM error